# Get number and following characters in string using regex

Tags: regex

For example, i have the string `PIRITON 4MG 10TABLET`. I would like to separate them into the drug name `PIRITON 4MG` and the quantity `10TABLET`. Sometimes there would be a space in between the integer quantity (e.g `10`) and the package type (e.g. `TABLET`) can be different as well e.g. `tablet`, `strip`, `bottle` etc.

Currently, I have the following regex:

```
.(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)(\s|)(TAB|tab|TABLET|tablet|strip|STRIP|bottle|BOTTLE|tube|TUBE|sachet|SACHET)
```

However, i'd like it to get whatever characters that follows the integer, but ignore integers followed by `MG` or `ML` to exclude the weight (e.g. `4MG`). This is so to include package types that i've not thought of beforehand in my results. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is simpler than you think. The pattern appears to be something like this:

> Drug name, some number, some units, some number again, some other units

The exact separators, etc. don't actually matter: you can effectively use the numbers to identify your other components:

```
(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)
```

Strip the groups before using them to avoid problems with optional whitespace (always in groups 1, 3, 5). If you want to always skip the amount, you don't need to capture it:

```
(\D+)\d+\D+(\d+)(\D+)
```

If you want to group the unit size into the drug name, capture them together:

```
(\D+\d+\D+)(\d+)(\D+)
```

By using `\D+`, you avoid hard coding your unit name at all, so mixed cases, plurals and new units won't be a problem to match.

Answer (score 0):

You might use 2 capturing groups:

`^(.+?[ ]+\d+(?:M[GL]))[ ]+(\d+[ ]*.+)$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gg1lyT/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert start of the line
- `(` Start capturing group

  - `.+?[ ]+\d+M[GL]` Match any character one or more times non greedy, one or more times a space followed by a digit and MG or ML using a character class
- `)` Close capturing group
- `[ ]+` Match one or more times a space
- `(` Start capturing group

  - `\d+[ ]*.+` Match one or more times a digit followed by zero or more times a space and any character one or more times
- `)` Close capturing group
- `$` Assert the end of the string